# How do i display Firebase formatting errors as an Alert and display it to the user?

Tags: swift, firebase

so i was working on this login and sign up screen with Firebase, whenever I format the email incorrectly or don't make the password 6 letters long, how do i display it as an Alert?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you asking how to display a popup alert box in Swift? If so, do you have the code you've attempted as that's how this site works. If you don't have the code yet, there are hundreds of tutorials on how to do that. Start there, write some code and report back when you get stuck. In the meantime, please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in my firebase code, the first is to define what has to be in the fields and the second is the pop up alert and what you want it to say if it doesnt meet the requirements for your registration or login info.

```
   @objc private func registerButtonTapped() {
        emailField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
        firstNameField.resignFirstResponder()
        lastNameField.resignFirstResponder()

        guard let firstName = firstNameField.text,
            let lastName = lastNameField.text,
            let email = emailField.text,
            let password = passwordField.text,
            !email.isEmpty,
            !password.isEmpty,
            !firstName.isEmpty,
            !lastName.isEmpty,
            password.count >= 6 else {
                alertUserLoginError()
                return
        }


func alertUserLoginError(message: String = "Please enter all information to create a new account.") {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Woops",
                                      message: message,
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Dismiss",
                                      style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
```